# Реализовать агрумент функции как указатель в C++

Tags: java

Как можно реализовать вот пример такой функции на JAVA (функция написана на сях)

```
void sickforce(int &x, int &y){
//много магии
}
```

А именно интересуют меня указатели &.

> В Java нет операций взятия адреса (&) или взятия объекта по адресу
>   (*). Звёздочка в Java означает умножение, и только. Амперсанд (&)
>   означает всего лишь «побитовое и» (двойной амперсанд — «логическое
>   и»).

Вот код без магии

```
int RSA::Euclidean(int a, int mod,int &x, int &y){
    if (mod == 0){
        x = 1; y = 0;
        return a;
    }
    int x1, y1;
    int d1 = Euclidean(mod, a%mod, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / mod)*y1;
    std::cout << std::endl << y << " " << x << std::endl;
    return d1;
}
```

Comment: Что вы конкретно хотите сделать? Приведите конкретный пример, без магии.

Comment: @LEQADA окей сейчас прикреплю код из C++ сюда, который надо трансфернуть в JAVA

Comment: В java все параметры передаются по значению. По ссылке нельзя передать. Если вам нужно чтото вернуть из функции, создайте класс с полями и возвращайте его экземляр

Comment: @zenden2k, ну, отчего же, в принципе можно. Только надо передать *массив* (а он может быть и из одного элемента).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае можно сделать класс Point

```
public class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
//конструкторы, геттеры/сеттеры
}
```

и соответственно функция будет выглядеть так:

```
public int euclidean(int a, int mod, Point p) {
    if (mod == 0) {
        p.setX(1); p.setY(0);
        return a;
    }
    ...
}
```